# The definition of stationary distribution of a Markov chain seems strange

Tags: matrices, definition, markov-chains

In [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/stationary-distributions/) as well as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Stationary_distribution), the definition of stationary distribution of Markov chain is $\pi P = \pi$, in which $\pi$ a state distribution and $P$ the transition matrix. Why was it defined that way?

I think it makes way more sense if it is defined as $P\pi$, since by the definition of matrix multiplication, $P\pi$ means $P$ transforms $\pi$ versus a distribution transform the transition matrix.

My guess is that it is due to the defition of transition matrix. According to 11.1.2 [here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Echance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter11.pdf), row $i$ of the transition matrix lays out the probability of what happen after state $i$. Therefore, we want $pi$ to be a row matrix, and in order to make the shape compatible in multiplication, it must be $\pi P$ instead of $P\pi$. However, I could not see which is more correct.

Comment: Then what about the definition of matrix vector multiplication? Interpreting as “vector is transforming the matrix” feels a bit strange to me.

Comment: I think I get it now, using $AB = (B^T A^T)^T. Please make your comments an answer so that I can accept

Comment: I was too confined on the matrix-vector multiplication that the stationary distribution definition seems strange. Your second answer dealt with it, so all good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was defined that way because the $(i,j)$-th entry of transition matrix $P$ was defined in a certain way, namely, that $p_{ij}$ is the probability of jumping from state $i$ to state $j$ (rather than from state $j$ to state $i$).

It feels strange to have the vector-matrix multiplication $\rm v^\top M$ instead of the more common matrix-vector multiplication $\rm M v$ because you're used to reading function composition from right to left ;-)